# Javascript values don't seen to be setting correctly

Tags: jquery

I'm using Javascript to update some values of hidden form fields which are latter used to work out a total. This was working fine but now something odd seems to be happening and I'm at a lose to work out what.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="membership[<?php echo $row_id; ?>][total]" class="<?php echo $row_id; ?>total" value="<?php echo $social_prices[$row['membership']]; ?>">
```

In my total function if I console.log the whole object I get:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="membership[1][total]" class="1total" value="43.5">
```

but if I just grab the value I get the original value of the field, which is 24.. so the total is being worked out using the original values rather than the updated ones...

here's how I'm doing the console.log;

```
console.log(this);
console.log((this.value));
```

This is how I'm updating the value:

```
$('.'+membership+'total').val(total);
```

if I run this line right after that one I get back the right value:

```
alert($('.'+membership+'total').val());
```

But when I try my total function it all goes wrong here is some of the code from the function I won;t post the whole lot cos it's really long.

```
   var total = 0;
   $('input:hidden').each(function () {
   // I'm using this to make sure I get only the field I want to add together
  var result = name.match(/total/g);
  if((result)){
     console.log(this);
     console.log((this.value));
     total = total + parseFloat((this).value);
   } 
   });
```

Comment: What's the `total` function?

Comment: Can you post your example on jsfiddle or jsbin? Or just paste your code here.

Comment: how you update the value? document.getelementbyid(x).value = xxx ?

Comment: I've added more code to the question.. hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.'+membership+'total').attr('defaultValue', 'newValue');
```

to change the default value that comes from.

other than that, .val works perfectly on the DOM

Answer (score 0):

The reason it can't be found is *probably* that your class name is invalid. It begins with a digit, which is not allowed. The resictions for class names is as follows:

```
Naming rules:

Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), and underscores ("_")
In HTML, all values are case-insensitive
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_class.asp

A solution may be to swap the word and the number: `class="total1"`. This way the name is valid yet you can put the same information in the identifier.